# Как без перезагрузки обновить список сообщений?

Tags: ajax

Здравствуйте!)
Если кто знает, подскажите, пожалуйста..

Есть БД с сообщениями (гостевая книга) и основной класс `Message`, на главной странице сообщения отображаются в порядке убывания даты.

Когда добавляем новое сообщение в БД, оно добавляется. Создается новый объект класса `Message` (делаю через AJAX-запрос, делаю ёparseJSONё возвращенного массива с введенными полями).

Но как без перезагрузки обновить список сообщений - не знаю.

```
$('form').submit ( function( e ){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
      url : 'save1.php',
      type : 'post',
      data : $('form').serialize()
  }).done( function ( data ){

        var result = $.parseJSON( data );

        $("#block").append( result ); // не работает..
      });
});
```

На главной странице сообщения выводятся методом `Меssage:getList` и каждое сообщение оформляется div-ом класса `block`.

```
$arMessages = Message::getList(); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($arMessages)) 
{ 
?>
<div id="block" class="w"> 
     <p> <strong>Посетитель :  </strong><? echo $row['username'] ?></p>
     <p><strong> Email :  </strong> <? echo $row['email'] ?> </p> 
     <p><strong> Дата добавления : </strong><? echo $row['date'] ?> </p>
     <p><strong> Сообщение : </strong><? echo $row['msg'] ?> </p> <br />
     <button class="j-delete" data-id=" <? echo $row['id'] ?>"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, пример ответа сервера. В каком виде приходят данные в data (ответ на аякс запрос)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В связи с появившейся дискуссией меняю ответ предыдущий.

```
$arMessages = Message::getList(); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($arMessages)) 
{ 
?>
<div id="block<?echo $row['id']?>" class="w"> //создаем уникальные id сообщений 
     <p> <strong>Посетитель :  </strong><? echo $row['username'] ?></p>
     <p><strong> Email :  </strong> <? echo $row['email'] ?> </p> 
     <p><strong> Дата добавления : </strong><? echo $row['date'] ?> </p>
     <p><strong> Сообщение : </strong><? echo $row['msg'] ?> </p> <br />
     <button class="j-delete" data-id=" <? echo $row['id'] ?>"></button>
</div>
```

В js

```
$('form').submit ( function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({url : 'save1.php', type : 'post', data : $('form').serialize()}).done( function ( data ){
        var result = $.parseJSON( data ); 
        var commentline = '<div id="block{id}" class="w"><p><strong>Посетитель :</strong> {username}</p><p><strong>Email :</strong> {email}</p><p><strong>Дата добавления:</strong> {date}</p><p><strong>Сообщение :</strong> {msg}</p></div>';
        var html = commentline.replace(/\{id\}/,result.id).replace(/\{username\}/,result.username).replace(/\{email\}/,result.email).replace(/\{date\}/,result.date).replace(/\{msg\}/,result.msg);
        $("#msgBlock").preppend( html ); //добавляем элемент в родительский блок. Нужно родителю в котором все комментарии лежат, присвоить id и уже в него вставлять новые сообщения
    });
});
```

Comment: ну да, а потом сидеть часами и материться глядя на абсолютно не читаемый JS)))) json хорошо когда работа идет с api или реально большими массивами однородных данных, но в случае вывести 1 сообщение много проще и чище отдать в ответе кусок верстки и не заморачиваться. это экономия и времени и нервов..

Comment: уже что-то понятно стало, спасибо))

только тут вот что

$arMessages = Message::getList();  
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($arMessages))  
{  
?> 
<div id="block" class="w">  
     <p> <strong>Посетитель :  </strong><? echo $row['username'] ?></p> 
     <p><strong> Email :  </strong> <? echo $row['email'] ?> </p>  
     <p><strong> Дата добавления : </strong><? echo $row['date'] ?> </p> 
     <p><strong> Сообщение : </strong><? echo $row['msg'] ?> </p> <br /> 
</div

это block в цикле вывода метода получить список сообщений..

Comment: Вот зачем вы учите неправильным вещам? Как раз получать данные для таких целей как сообщение, ник, айди  и сопутствующее лучше в джейсоне. А если запрашивать мы станем не 1 сообщение, последние 100 сообщений пользователя? Сидеть и материться количеству передаваемых данных? А если нам понадобится поправить вывод, сидеть и материться невозможности исправить, атк как приходит кусок хтмл? Или потом его парсить через одно место и все-равно работать с данными? А если на разных страницах одни и теже данные используются по разному и для блоков надо разная верстка?

Comment: Извините, вопрос по поводу "И не слушайте советов "возвращать сразу кусок html"" - чем плох данные метод? Считаю не стоит выносить разметку страницы в js или я не прав?...

Comment: @Baron, зависит от задачи. Точно не стоит гонять лишние данные по сети. Ведь некоторые люди ходят в интернет со смартфонов, зачем им лишний трафик? Если у вас данные, которые могут использоваться многократно в разных комбинациях - зачем генерировать на сервере жесткие рамки и отдавать хтмл - дальше вы не сможет работать с этими данными на клиенте, у вас только готовый кусок кода.

Comment: что же делать с циклом..и div-м block внутри этого цикла..?

Comment: В рамках данного вопроса затрудняюсь ответить сразу- так как много уточняющих вопросов возникает. Если хотите, обратитесь в скайпе - логин igor.kuzko . Подскажу. Плюс тут еще почитайте, народ подтянется много хороших вариантов посоветует :)

Comment: увы,скайп не работает(

спасибо за ответы)

Comment: @АлександрМолофеев Можно использовать шаблонизаторы.
Vue.js, handlebars, JsRender.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно использовать

> `innerHTML`.

сделай

> alert(result);

и напиши что вывел

поэтому и не выводит, result должен содержать перед выводом текст
например попробуй вот так

> el.innerHTML='<h1>Ура</h1>';

Comment: пыталась сделать так 

 var el = document.getElementByld("block"); // куда поместить
   el.innerHTML += result;  

но без результата..

Comment: выводиь object Object

Comment: alert(result.username)  получилось..
но вот в этот блок кода как добавить result.username  и тд, он из index.php

$arMessages = Message::getList();  
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($arMessages))  
{  
?> 
<div id="block" class="w">  
     <p> <strong>Посетитель :  </strong><? echo $row['username'] ?></p> 
     <p><strong> Email :  </strong> <? echo $row['email'] ?> </p>  
     <p><strong> Дата добавления : </strong><? echo $row['date'] ?> </p> 
     <p><strong> Сообщение : </strong><? echo $row['msg'] ?> </p> <br /> 
</div>

Comment: не alert надо а console.log(result) и смотреть в консоли результат

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#block").preppend( html_data );    // вставит первым
```

а из скрипта сервера, который записывает сообщение в базу обработав запрос, лучше возвращать сразу кусок верстки - это много проще для всех...

Comment: скрипт  save.php который сохраняет возвращает вот что

if ($newMessage->save()){
  
  $arReturn = array(
     'username'=> $username,
     'email'=> $email,
  'msg'=> $msg
  );
  echo json_encode( $arReturn);
  };

 }
попробовала сделать
var result = $.parseJSON( data );
$("#block").prepend( result );  - тоже ничего не получилось..

Comment: save.php:  
if ($newMessage->save()){ ?>  
<div id="block" class="w">   
     <p> <strong>Посетитель :  </strong><?=$username?></p>  
     <p><strong> Email :  </strong> <?=$email?> </p>   
     <p><strong> Дата добавления : </strong><?=$date?> </p>  
     <p><strong> Сообщение : </strong><?=$msg?> </p> <br />  
     <button class="j-delete" data-id="<?=$id?>"></button>  
</div>  
<?}?>  

JS:
 $.ajax({
      url : 'save1.php',
      type : 'post',
      data : $('form').serialize(),
      success:function(html){
            $("#block").append( html );
      }
  });

Comment: и чтото мне подсказывает что селектор #block у вас не правильный, получается что вы вставляете сообщение в сообщение а не в контейнер сообщений

Comment: a что вернул parseJSON нельзя использовать..?
лучше через него бы..

Comment: получается да..контейнера нет никакого..
есть циклический вывод всех сообщений через метод Message:getList..

полученный из него массив сообщений прогоняю через цикл и каждое сообщение оформляю в виде блока..

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form').submit ( function( e ){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
      url : 'save1.php',
      type : 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      data : $('form').serialize(),
      success: function(result){
          if (result.res=='ok'){
              $('.list').html(result.html);
          } else {
              alert('Error!');
          }
      }

  });
});
```

В save1.php выполнить необходимые дейсвия, по логике названия файла - сохранение, затем в переменную например $html - формируете строку вывода.

```
$html = '';
$arMessages = Message::getList(); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($arMessages)) 
{ 
     $html.='
     <div id="block_'.$row["id"].'" class="w"> 
          <p> <strong>Посетитель :  </strong>'.$row["username"].'</p>
          <p><strong> Email :  </strong> '.$row["email"].'</p> 
          <p><strong> Дата добавления : </strong>'.$row["date"].'</p>
          <p><strong> Сообщение : </strong>'.$row["msg"].'</p> <br />
          <button class="j-delete" data-id="'.$row["id"].'"></button>
      </div>';
}
echo json_encode(array('res'=>'ok','html'=>$html));
exit;
```

И все, больше ничего не требуется. Пробуйте, не получится - будем разбираться.

Comment: а где же все-таки переменую html объявлять?

может в  html складывать все сообщения через цикл прошедшие...а потом к ней прибавлять в начало html_1 где div  с новым сообщением..

Comment: только мне все равно этот подход не нравится..

Comment: обьявлять в save1.php
у вас должен быть общий блок для сообщений, например - <div class="list"></div>
внутри него добавляются блоки с классом "w". Если необходимо добавить к уже существующим, то надо в html записать только один блок и потом через append в js добавить содержимое нового блока.
$('.list').append(res.html); Но метод у вас в save1.php как я понимаю получает все сообщения а не последнее, следовательно логичным было бы полностью обновить блок и нечего не аппендить.
Немного подреактировал ответ, посмотрите.

Comment: ну нравится, не нравится, а писать html в js это нонсенс) 
Схема работы этого метода - отправляете запрос, сохраняете или что там надо делаете, рендерите новые блоки, кодируете ответ в json и через js уже заменяете содержимое необходимого блока. Может кто-то предложит иной вариант, единственно верного нету)

Comment: нет, save.php  принимает только последнее..

Comment: ну это понятно что последнее, а вернуть то он может все) у вас же есть метод Message::getList(); вот после сохранения через него и возвращайте все сообщения.

Comment: Тоесть, если там 100500 сообщений нужно вместо динамического добавления последнего, возвращать в се и рендерить заново такой объем элементов? Вы в это сами верите, что правильный вариант?

Comment: а динамическое добавление будет при этом?

перезагрузка страницы не нужна..

Comment: Анна, допишите еще в класс Message метод, который будет возвращать одну запись по last_insert_id. И тогда в $html можно будет поместить только последнее сообщение и добавить на страницу через append.
@iKuzko При большой нагрузке будут проблемы, согласен. Не подумал